# Error: list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: jquery, python, arrays, object, pyramid

I have a form which gets pre-populated by an Object. Framework: Pyramid, IDE: PyCharm

On the page I have extra fields for users to add additional phone numbers and emails. For example individual phone objects {tag:work, value:555} would get pushed into the phones[] array inside of the person object. Then I need to send that new info back to the server.

jQuery

```
// Person
var person = {
    username : profileData.username,
    firstName : "",
    lastName : "",
    phones : [],
    emails : [],
    organization : "",
    title : ""
}

// Original Profile
person.firstName = $('#profile-firstname').val();
person.lastName  = $('#profile-lastname').val();
person.organization = $('#profile-company').val();
person.title  = $('#profile-title').val();

// Added Profile
var phoneObjs   = {};
var emailObjs   = {};
var extraPhones = [];
var extraEmails = [];
var addedPhones = $('.added_phone');
var addedEmails = $('.added_email');

addedPhones.each( function(i) {
    //console.log(i);
    var tag = $(this).children("label").text();
    var value = $(this).children("input").val();
    phoneObjs = $(this).map(function(i,el) {
        var $el = $(el);
        return {
            tag: tag,
            value:value
        };
    }).get();
    person.phones.push(phoneObjs);
    console.log(phoneObjs);
});
```

Python

```
def save_profile(self):
    success_msgs = ['Saved! Worry not, nothing sent to the NSA... as far as we know', "Profile Saved, doesn't it feel great to be updated?"]
    error_msgs = ['Internets are clogged up, our monkeys are checking it out', 'Hmm, everything look correct below?', "A BUG! Probably in our code, we're checking it out"]
    try:
        json = self.request.json_body
        first_name = str(json['firstName'])
        last_name = str(json['lastName'])
        organization = str(json['organization'])
        title = str(json['title'])
        phones = (json['phones'])
        emails = (json['emails'])
        self.profiles.update(firstName=first_name, lastName=last_name, organization=organization, title=title, emails=emails, phones=phones)
        #print phones
        value = {'result': 'success', 'message': random.choice(success_msgs)}
    except Exception, err:
        print err
        value = {'result': 'error', 'message': random.choice(error_msgs)}

    #returns a json response
    return self.respond(value)
```

profile.update

```
if tools.not_blank(phones):
        lst = phones
        cnt = len(lst)
        current = profile.phones
        for x in xrange(cnt):
            o = lst[x]
            #key = o.get("key", o.get("guid", None))
            lbl = o["label"]
            tag = o.get("tag", None)
            c = [c for c in current if c.label == lbl]
            c = c[0] if len(c) > 0 else None
            if c:
                m, k = self.codex.decode_composite(c.id)
                if tools.not_blank(tag):
                    tag = tag.lower().title()
                    if c.tag != tag:
                        c.tag = tag
                        self.get_query("UPDATE member_phone SET Type = @tag WHERE ID = @id;", {"tag": tag, "id": k}).update()
            else:
                #create a new email address for this member
                self.members.register_phone_number(member=member, telephone=lbl, tag=tag)

    if tools.is_blank(remove):
        return profile
```

**The IDE will throw the "list indices must be integers, not str" error here**

Any thoughts? Not sure what is wrong here.

```
self.profiles.update(firstName=first_name, lastName=last_name, organization=organization, title=title, emails=emails, phones=phones)
```

The form with added fields creates the correct object here

[image]
[image]

Comment: What IDE are you talking about? It may also be helpful to tell us what framework this is, or at least what `self.profiles` is.

Comment: Would you please post the traceback information? And what do you do in `self.profiles.update()` method?

Comment: Sorry it's PyCharm, in the Pyramid Framework, adding the profiles.update to the original code... I'm actually getting close, my problem is that I'm passing in a nested Array inside of an Array and that's causing the problem I believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with my jQuery, when I dived into the self.profiles.update()

```
if tools.not_blank(phones):
        lst = phones
        cnt = len(lst)
        current = profile.phones
        for x in xrange(cnt):
            o = lst[x]
            #key = o.get("key", o.get("guid", None))
            lbl = o["label"]
```

First problem is that lbl = 0["label"] the original developer was expecting label for Phones instead of value that I was passing.

2nd thing, our iOS dev pointed out that I had an nested Array `[[]]` didn't notice that, so back again in the jQuery:

Had to change: `person.phones.push(phoneObjs);` to `person.phones = phoneObjs;`

Now it just returns `[]` for Phones and no list error :)

Updated jQuery

```
addedPhones.each( function(i) {
    var tag = $(this).children("label").text();
    var value = $(this).children("input").val();
    phoneObjs = $(this).map(function(i,el) {
        var $el = $(el);
        return {
            tag: tag,
            label:value
        };
    }).get();
    person.phones = phoneObjs;
    console.log(phoneObjs);
});
```